# How do i customise product template views by inheritance in odoo 14?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, odoo-14

I'm trying to add a custom field in product_templte_form_vieew by doing this :

```
<!-- product template -->
<record id="mymoduleproduct_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">mymodule.product</field>
    <field name="model">mymodule.product</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='general_information']/group[2]" position="attributes">
            <field name="prixass"/>
            <field name="taxes_id" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </field>  
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

No error  in  excution  but it seems to not work. Need help to detect or correct what is wrong.

I have already define ‘prixass’ fields like this :

```
class MyModuleProduct(models.Model):
    _name = "mymodule.product"
    _description = "table des articles"
    _inherit = "product.template"

    prixass = fields.Float(string='Prix Assurance')
    taxes_id = fields.Many2many('account.tax', 'product_hospi_taxes', 'prod_hospi_id', 'tax_id', string='Customer Taxes')
    supplier_taxes_id = fields.Many2many('account.tax', 'product_hospi_supplier_taxes', 'prod_hospi_id', 'tax_id', string='Vendor Taxes')
    route_ids = fields.Many2many('stock.location.route', 'stock_route_product_hospi', 'product_hospi_id', 'route_id', string='Routes',)
```

Also i’ld like to remove the fields taxes_id from the view, how do i do ?

.
[the resume of the question in image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt6Bx.png)

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but this work for me now

```
//model
class MyModuleProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.template"

    prixass = fields.Float(string='Prix Assurance')
    taxes_id = fields.Many2many('account.tax', 'product_hospi_taxes', 'prod_hospi_id', 'tax_id', string='Customer Taxes')
    supplier_taxes_id = fields.Many2many('account.tax', 'product_hospi_supplier_taxes', 'prod_hospi_id', 'tax_id', string='Vendor Taxes')
    route_ids = fields.Many2many('stock.location.route', 'stock_route_product_hospi', 'product_hospi_id', 'route_id', string='Routes',)


//views
<record id="product_inherit_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.template</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='general_information']/group[1]" position="after">
            <group>
                <field name="prixass"/>
            </group>
        </xpath>
        <field name="taxes_id" position="replace">
            <field name="taxes_id" invisible="1"/>
        </field> 
</record>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
class MyModuleProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.template"

    prixass = fields.Float(string='Prix Assurance')
    taxes_id = fields.Many2many('account.tax', 'product_hospi_taxes', 'prod_hospi_id', 'tax_id', string='Customer Taxes')
    supplier_taxes_id = fields.Many2many('account.tax', 'product_hospi_supplier_taxes', 'prod_hospi_id', 'tax_id', string='Vendor Taxes')
    route_ids = fields.Many2many('stock.location.route', 'stock_route_product_hospi', 'product_hospi_id', 'route_id', string='Routes',)
```

```html
<record id="product_inherit_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.template</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='general_information']/field[@name='default_code']" position="after">
            <field name="prixass"/>
        </xpath>
        <field name="taxes_id" position="replace">
                <field name="taxes_id" invisible="1"/>
            </field>  
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: I got an error after aplying this: 
L'élément '<xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='general_information']/field[@name='default_code']">' ne peut être localisé dans la vue parente

View name: product.template
Error context:
 view: ir.ui.view(1088,)
 xmlid: product_inherit_view
 view.model: product.template
 view.parent: ir.ui.view(443,)
 file: /opt/odoo/custom/clinic/views/params.xml